# validating decimal numbers in culture

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, decimal

can anyone please explain why, in 'en-GB' culture formatting, the decimal.Parse() function would return 15 for 1,5?

I see the same result for 'de' culture when inputting 1.5, the return is 15.

I know this is programmatically correct, I'm just trying to understand why this is correct. I've Googled this and come up with nothing :(

i'm trying to validate user inputs against culture, and populating the input field with a 0 when the parse fails, but populating the field with 15 when they've entered 1,5 doesn't feel right, i feel like it should be "failing" when a 1,5 is entered for english formating, instead of returning 15.

```
    try {
        validateSource.Text = decimal.Parse(validateThis, NumberStyles.Number, UserCulture).ToString();
    } catch {
        validateSource.Text = "0";
    }
```

Comment: Because `,` is the [`NumberGroupSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator(v=vs.100).ASPX)?!

Comment: but how does 1,5 equate to 15? I'm sorry if this seems like a stupid question to anyone else, but I'm dyslexic and this is really confusing me!

Comment: What do you think it should equate to?

Comment: @Stuart: `decimal.Parse` does not count the number of places in each group. However, if you don't want to allow the group-separator  you can use `NumberStyles.Float` instead of `NumberStyles.Number`(default, includes `AllowThousands` which is the group-separator): `if(decimal.TryParse("1,5", NumberStyles.Float, new CultureInfo("en-GB"), out dec)){}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`,` is the [`NumberGroupSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) in the UK culture. There's no validation in terms of how many digits are in each group. So "1,2,3" would be parsed as 123, even though that's not how we'd normally expect it to be written.

While it would make sense for parsing to check the [`NumberGroupSizes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupsizes(v=vs.110).aspx) property, it simply doesn't.

You could emulate this check in a *very* primitive fashion by formatting the result of parsing, and see whether that's equal to the original input:

```
decimal value;
if (decimal.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.Number, culture, out value))
{
    if (text != value.ToString("N", culture))
    {
        // Okay, looks like something's up... report an error
    }
}
```

Of course, that would the stop someone from entering "1234.56" as it would expect "1,234.56"... you might want to check *multiple* pattern formats, e.g. "N" and "G", to see whether it matches any of them.

Comment: just like 1,000 is the same at 1000 right? NOW I get it! I think I just needed it explained a different way, THANK YOU.

Comment: Or he could parse it with `NumberStyles.Float` to disallow the group separator. Would that be a viable approach?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: If the OP wants to disallow that, yes. It depends on the requirements.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Possibly - although AllowExponent and AllowTrailingWhite may be undesirable. Anyway, hopefully the OP has enough to work with now :)

Comment: thank you so much for this answer, this has helped me understand better what is happening now! :) much appreciated as always.